# How to write correct query to find students not currently in a course

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find remaining students which are available to enrol into a course. To do this I need to find students who are currently active and who are not currently in the course. Bu I think the query I am writing is incorrect because it keeps displaying an empty set of results when I run the query how can I find the remaining students who ar able to enrol in the course?

Below is current query:

```
SELECT  st.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM    Course c
        INNER JOIN Student_Course sc
            ON c.CourseId = sc.CourseId
        INNER JOIN Student st
            ON sc.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE   (c.CourseId = 1 AND
        sc.StudentId IS NULL
        AND st.Active = 1)
ORDER   BY st.StudentAlias
```

Below are the tables:

**Student:** (List of all Students)

```
StudentId  StudentAlias  StudentForename  StudentSurname  Active
1          u09382        James            Smith           1
2          u83923        John             Brooks          1
3          u38292        Karen            Bradshaw        0
4          u20039        Chris            Cameron         1
5          u39399        Jane             Fields          1
```

**Course:** (List of all Courses)

```
CourseId  CourseNo  CourseName
1         INFO121   ICT
2         BUS122    Business and Finance
3         ENG432    English Language
```

**Student_Course:** (List of Students enrolled in respective courses)

```
StudentId  CourseId
1          1
1          3
2          1
4          2
5          2
```

So for example if I select `CourseId = 1`, then it should display students who are active but yet obviously not in  `CourseId = 1` which means it it should display these students below for possibility of enrollment into course:

```
4 - Chris Cameron
5 - Jane Fields
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT s.studentId, s.Forename
FROM Student s
WHERE s.studentId NOT IN (SELECT studentId 
FROM  Student_Course c WHERE c.courseId = 1) AND s.Active = 1
```

The inner subquery return student of courseId =1 and in outer query we filter those students.

Comment: Try a left join solution rather than a subselect. Subselects are normally slower

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  st.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM    Course c
        INNER JOIN Student_Course sc
            ON c.CourseId = sc.CourseId
        INNER JOIN Student st
            ON sc.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE   (sc.CourseId <> 1
        AND st.Active = 1)
ORDER   BY st.StudentAlias
```

Comment: What does `<> 1` mean? never seen that before

Comment: <> means not equals to. (sc.CourseId!=1)

Comment: @Sachin Ahh, ok, I will test it

Comment: I already have a correct answer below, when I tested your query only issue was that it displayed a student who is already in the course. Thanks for the attempt anyway.

Comment: I dont' think this query returns what the OP wants - it will return a list of all student/course tuples with the exception of courseID 1.

Answer (score 0):

To find active students not on a course then something like this:-

```
SELECT  st.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM    Student st
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Course sc ON sc.StudentId = st.StudentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Course c ON c.CourseId = sc.CourseId
WHERE   c.CourseId IS NULL
AND st.Active = 1
ORDER   BY st.StudentAlias
```

If you want to check students not on a particular course then

```
SELECT  st.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname
FROM    Student st
LEFT OUTER JOIN Student_Course sc ON sc.StudentId = st.StudentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Course c ON c.CourseId = sc.CourseId AND CourseId = 1
WHERE   c.CourseId IS NULL
AND st.Active = 1
ORDER   BY st.StudentAlias
```

Put the course to check in the ON clause

Comment: Hi, tested your query but still outputs an empty set of results

Comment: That is down to your test data. The only active students are id 1, 2, 4 and 5 and they all have courses.

Comment: This will return a list of all students that are active, but not enrolled in /any/ course. You should add a join condition for the specific course ID.